# How to load mod_spatialite QGIS extention on macOS

Tags: python, qgis, spatialite

I am using the latest version to have python on my macOS. I load the database in QGIS but I didn't work mod_spatialite. I always got an error: error:  image not fou

```html
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.Connection('/Users/aysekaracaorenli/Desktop/python/tompkins.sqlite')
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.execute('SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite")')
```

```html
File "/Users/aysekaracaorenli/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 13, in <module>
    conn.execute('SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite")')

OperationalError: dlopen(mod_spatialite.dylib, 10): image not found
```